# Problem of result of TopProbabilities in NetModel

Tags: bugs, neural-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.0.0**

I'm on Mathematica 11.3, Classify model could use TopProbabilities without designating an integer.

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MHkf.png"]
model=NetModel["VGG-16 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]
model[img,"TopProbabilities"]
```

How to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should post actual code instead of images of code. The message with the `Rule` is clearly a bug, and bugs should be reported to WRI.  You seem to have found a workaround for this bug, but I would still recommend reporting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in Version 12, or upgrade your `NeuralNetworks` Framework.

```
PacletUpdate["NeuralNetworks"]
```

[image]

**Remark:**

This was caused by some bug in 11.3's decoder function.

In `/Decoder/Classes.m`, find function `topProbs[labels_]` and modify the return from

```
Map[Thread@*Apply[Rule], labelsValues, {-3}]
```

to

```
Map[Thread@*Apply[Rule], labelsValues, {Depth[input] - 2}]
```